# Grouping similar items from CSV file column as primary key

Tags: java, csv

I have a large CSV file with data similar to this

```
User ID       Group
ABC           Group1   
DEF           Group2
ABC           Group3
GHI           Group4
XYZ           Group2
UVW           Group5
XYZ           Group1
ABC           Group1
DEF           Group2
```

i need to group these items in such a way that number of times group attribute is repeated in a user id and get a value such that

```
ABC   Group1 ->2
ABC   Group3 ->1
DEF   Group2 ->2
GHI   Group4 ->1
UVW   Group5 ->1
XYZ   Group2 ->1
XYZ   Group1 ->1
```

Are there any clustering algorithm to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clustering' algorithm? A parallelizable algorithm?

Comment: And how large is your CSV? Can you fit it in memory?

Comment: CSV file is of 30,000 lines. Might be more in some cases.

Comment: 30.000 lines should fit in memory nicely for a modern machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I will do somethink like this if you don't want to store all the data in memory:

```
public class Tester {
public static Multiset<String> getMultisetFromCSV(String csvFileName, String lineDelimiter) throws IOException {
    Multiset<String> mapper = TreeMultiset.create();


    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileName));

        String[] currLineSplitted;

        while(reader.ready()) {
            currLineSplitted = reader.readLine().split(lineDelimiter);
            mapper.add(currLineSplitted[0] + "-" + currLineSplitted[1]);
        }

        return mapper;
    } finally {
        if(reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Multiset<String> set = getMultisetFromCSV("csv", ",");

    for(String key : set.elementSet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " : " + set.count(key));
    }


}
```

}

In this way you're able to construct your map very easily. After that, for each key you can count the number of items associated to it using the [count method](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset).

Comment: This still keeps most of the data in memory, but for 30K records that won't be a problem. 

Further, I wouldn't do set.count(key) in the for loop, that's a O(n*log(n)) operation. Using Multiset.Entry<String> entry: set.iterator(), and pring entry.getElement() + ": " + entry.getCount() is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to use Guava's TreeMultiset: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html.

Create a class UserGroup with fields userId and group and let it implement Comparable, by comparing first on userId and then on group.

Read in your csv file, create a UserGroup per line and add it to the MultiSet,

To get the result, use the MultiSet.iterator(), and print entry.getElement() and entry.getCount().

If you get an Out-Of-Memory, and you can't assign enough memory, you could use an external (merge) sort https://code.google.com/p/externalsortinginjava/

Comment: The class UserGroup is not really necessary, you can use a String with userId + " "+group concatenated, provided that userId does not contain any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 you can write something like:

```
Map<String, Long> userGroup = Files.lines(csvFile, UTF_8)
                .skip(1) //skip headers
                .map(s -> s.split("\\s+")) //split on space
                .map(array -> array[0] + " " + array[1]) //user + " " + group
                //collect into a TreeMap, for sorting
                //the key is the user/group and the value the number of occurences
                .collect(groupingBy(ug -> ug, TreeMap::new, counting()));
```

<sub>note: requires the following static imports: `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;` and `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;`</sub>